# Connecting Stereo Jack Socket

Tags: amplifier, audio, connector, socket, stereo

I have the following Stereo Jack Socket, but I think Its pin layout is different than the socket images available on the internet.

Please show me how to connect this female socket to the circuit (L, R, G)

[image]
[image]

Comment: What I always do: get a 3.5mm jack plug and a multimeter, then find what is connected to what. Other option without a multimeter: get a battery (1.5 V or 9V, it does not matter), a 1 k ohm resistor and headphones. Put the headphones on, not on your ears but a bit more to the front of your face, this is in case there are loud clicks. Now with battery and resistor in series, probe the contacts. It is easy to find ground, left and right that way.

Comment: Or if you do have a multimeter but no 3.5 mm jack: instead of the battery + resistor, use the multimeter in resistance measurement. The headphones will have some resistance (often 30 ohms or more) and you will hear clicks.

Comment: Look through the clear window on the top of the unit, and work out which contact is which.

Comment: Yes, multimeter helped. but there are two pins with no output/connections. Are they meant to leave unconnected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 5 pin stereo headphone jack.

[image]

The connections are common, left, left speaker, right speaker and right.

The speakers get disconnected when the headphone is plugged in.

Comment: So, I can leave 2 pins unconnected.

Comment: Hi Vishal, Yes, you can. Thank you.